# WinForms in Mono - Problems with form repainting

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, repaint

I have a WinForms Application. I need it to run also in Mono.

I have a problem with form repainting. There are many controls in the form. When I resize the form or when I try to update it (it needs to be updated on timer tick), the repainting does not work . Sometimes the controls are placed right, but it flickers, sometimes the the controls do not move or resize at all, some of the controls (buttons) seem to be disabled, some of them even disappear or are displayed twice.

In .NET I had similar problems, but enabling double-buffering on form solved them. But it seems that it does not work in Mono at all and I really don't know what to do.

On resize I need to move and resize the controls and redraw pictures in PictureBoxes.

I also have a problem with the above mentioned timer - the tick event fires only once and then almost everything on the form stops working, but I think it may be connected with the repainting problem.

If someone had an advice on how to correctly repaint a WinForms form in Mono, I would appreciate it.

Comment: “I need it to run also in Mono”. Give it up, unless you would like to address such issues fully on your own. Not many guys actively maintains that part recently, so issues won't soon be analyzed and fixed. There are other more reliable ways to write GUI applications for other platforms.

Comment: @LexLi normally you would be right with that kind of comment, but look at the master branch these days: there's a person who has started to maintain it: https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/master/mcs/class/System.Windows.Forms

Comment: so, @hinge: I recommend you to grab a nightly build, maybe your issue is fixed already

Comment: @knocte compared to the maturity of other approaches, I won't recommend WinForms. I know the facts that lately something happened again on Mono WinForms, but I doubt enough efforts have been invested, and make it production ready is even a longer road.

Comment: sure, but if @hinge has already big investments in the technology, rewriting everything might not be the best thing to do here; your advice seems more fit to people that want to start something new and need to choose a technology